# How to line clamp in the middle of the last word

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

I want to clamp the second line of text, BUT if there is a long word at the end, put the ellipsis in the middle of the word.

I currently have the following:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Here we have some long text that needs to be clamped at the 2nd line verylongwordverylongwordverylongwordverylongwordverylongwordverylongwordverylongwordverylongword
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is the following result:

[image: Expected result]

As you can see, the last word is long and should be cut off in the middle and not removed completely.

Is there a nice way to solve this?

Comment: Related Github discussions: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4406 & https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3937#issuecomment-1624382903

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`word-break: break-all;` will do exactly this.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break?retiredLocale=de

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-all;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Here we have some long text that needs to be clamped at the 2nd line verylongwordverylongwordverylongwordverylongwordverylongwordverylongwordverylongwordverylongword
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but this will also cause text to _wrap_ in the middle of a word as well, which may be undesirable.